# knockoutjs - accessing $parent/$root inside foreach binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/BFVAYQKBh3X67vrHz1En?p=preview) is a plunker code that I am working on. I have defined a VM which looks like this.

```
    var employee = function(fname,lname){
    var self= this;
    self.fname = ko.observable(fname);
    self.lname = ko.observable(lname);
    self.selectedElement = ko.observable('Default Value');
  }

  var vm = function(){
      var self = this;
      self.employees = new ko.observableArray([]);
      self.selectedElement = ko.observable(-1);

      var e1 = new employee('f1','l1');
      var e2 = new employee('f2','l2');
      self.employees.push(e1);
      self.employees.push(e2);
  };

  ko.applyBindings(vm,container);
```

And my code to display list of employees is

```
<body id="container">
<h1>Empoyees</h1>
<div>
  <div data-bind="foreach: employees">
    <h4 data-bind="text: 'Employee' + $index()"></h4>
    <span>First Name :</span>
    <span data-bind="text: fname"></span>
    <br/>

    <span>Last Name :</span>
    <span data-bind="text: fname"></span>
    <br/>

    <span data-bind="text: selectedElement()"></span>
    <!-- I want to access parents 'selectedElement' i.e. vm.slectedElement() -->
    <!--I tried below code but its causing binding error.-->
    <!-- <span data-bind="text: $parent.selectedElement()"></span> -->
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that lass '`employee`' and main view model '`vm`' both has identical property named ( `selectedElement` )

Now inside foreach binding I am trying to access '`selectedElement`' property of root/parent context but because I am inside foreach ko is accessing 'selectedElement' property of 'employee' class.

I tried using `$root` and `$parent` keywords to reach parent element property but its causing binding error.

Am I missing anything?  [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/BFVAYQKBh3X67vrHz1En?p=preview) is the plunker link again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were never creating an instance of your root view model. Change the initial call to

```
ko.applyBindings(new vm(),container);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/wRKfnJi9Jl9Rj2unbgQp?p=preview

When you do that, either `$root` or `$parent` will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @Jamiec for a quick response.  But, still I am scratching my head why everything else ( except $root/$parent ) worked without instantiating object of my view model.  May be I don't know basics.  Can you please throw some light on this?

Comment: @user2243747 knockout will accept a straight function as a view model, but probably `this` refers to the window object when you do that. It'll confuse the runtime's hierarchy of view models, so things like `$root` and `$parent` probably point to the wrong place.